# Find the dimension of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: extension-field, minimal-polynomials

What is the dimension of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)}$ over $\mathbb{Q}?$

Considering that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})} \subseteq \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)}$

$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)} : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})} : \mathbb{Q}] [\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)} : \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}]$

---

$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2}$

the minimal polynomial is $f(x) = x^2-5$ in fact $f(\sqrt{5}) = 0$ and $f(x)$ has no rational roots

---

$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i):\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}] = 2}$

the minimal polynomial is $f(x) = x^2 +1$ in fact $f(i) = 0$ and $f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}$

So $[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)} : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$

It's right?

Comment: You might want to use the \mathbb command more sparingly. That $\mathbb 5$ should be, simply, $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Final step could be more rigurous.  $$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)}:\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}] 
\leq 2,$$ since $t^2+1$ has coefficents in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, and has $i$ as root. In the other hand $$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5},i)}:\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}]>1, $$ since $i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{5})}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Hence the degree is $2$.